# Issue regarding heroku and flask

Tags: python, opencv, flask, heroku, mediapipe

I have made face recognisation using `OpenCv`, `mediapipe` and `python`. I created backend using `flask` and this is working completely fine on my PC but on deploying it on `heroku` is creating a error(`code=H10`).
Can anyone please fix this error?

`2022-02-20T09:03:40.710031+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=herokubkl.herokuapp.com request_id=67efdb2a-92e6-4304-ac32-2ac913a3d856 fwd="223.177.45.56" dyno=web.1 connect=5001ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

https://github.com/rawsome24/Zeet-Deployement-Test

Comment: Is your procfile good?

Comment: `web: gunicorn app:app`
This is my Procfile file.

Comment: try web: gunicorn sitename.wsgi

Comment: assuming you set your wsgi file

Comment: Still, I'm left with same error

Comment: you set up your wsgi file prpoerly?

Comment: ```from main import app
    import os
port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))   
 if __name__ == "__main__":<br/>
            app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)```<br/>

This is my wsgi file

Comment: Try this as your procfile: web: gunicorn app:app --log-file=-

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the port provided by Heroku

```
p = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
app.run(debug=True, port=p, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: Still getting same error

Comment: Check logs again (at startup). If the port is fine it could be memory or missing module

Comment: I'm sorry, if I sound noob I'm deploying website for first time on heroku. Can you please specify what I have to do? Please

Comment: Look at logs (in the Dashboard or with `heroku logs -a appname`) while you are deploying